# Backbone post call to download a excel file

Tags: file, post, backbone.js, download

I want to call a POST rest api from backbone with two long list of string as parameters in request body which will give me an Excel file as response. How can I do that in backbone? (FYI - the rest api are hosted at java/spring end.)

Comment: `content-disposition:attachment` and then pass the file as response

Comment: What do you mean *"two long list of string as parameters"*? 2 arrays of strings? Are these part of a model? What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: The problem is to make a post request to download a file. This is actually not a Backbone issue but pure Javascript/HTML. As Sandeep says, your server has to add a correct `Content-Disposition` header, but he has to make the post into a new window/tab to issue a download. Maybe a form element with a target, manually `submit()`ed can solve this.